# Using LIKE in a JOIN query

Tags: sql, join, left-join, sql-like

I have two separate data tables.

This is `Table1`:

```
Customer Name  Address 1       City     State  Zip
ACME COMPANY   1 Street Road   Maspeth  NY     11777
```

This is `Table2`:

```
Customer   Active Account   New Contact
ACME       Y                John Smith
```

I am running a query using the `JOIN` where *only include rows where the joined fields from both tables are equal*.

I am joining `Customer Name` from `Table1` and `Customer` from `Table2`. Obviously no match. What I am trying to do is show results where the first 4 characters match in each table so I get a result or match. Is this possible using `LIKE` or `LEFT`?

Comment: Depends on what type of sql server you're using for the syntax you need.

Comment: The simple answer is "yes, this is possible". What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's possible. 
But I doubt, that every name in table 2 only has 4 letters, so here's a solution where the name in table2 is the beginning of the name in table1.

Concat the string with a `%`. It's a placeholder/wildcard for "anything or nothing".

```
SELECT
*
FROM
Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CustomerName LIKE CONCAT(Table2.Customer, '%');
```

Concatenating of strings may work differently between DBMS.

Comment: Nice! How would you cope with the "first four characters match in each table"?

Comment: I was in doubt, that every name in table 2 only has 4 letters, so I provided a solution where the name in table2 is the beginning of the name in table1.

Comment: Actually LIKE might be better for me, too many matches where the criteria was met but not a "true" match. Let me try the LIKE CONCAT, will advise.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this should work:

```
Select *
From Table1, Table2 
Where Table1.CustomerName Like Cat('%',Trim(Table2.CustomerName),'%')
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  CONCAT for MySQL

Answer (score 2):

It probably is, though this might depend on the Database you are using. For example, in Microsoft SQL, it would work to use somthing like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table1] INNER JOIN [Table2]
ON LEFT([Table1].[Customer Name],4) = LEFT([Table2].[Customer],4)
```

Syntax may be different if using other RDBMS. What are you trying this on?

Comment: Thanks I will try this. MS ACCESS. I'm actually making a new table combining data from both.

Comment: Glad it it worked for you. I'd appreciate you checking this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to match first four Characters you can use following :

```
SELECT --your columns
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table T2
ON
SUBSTRING ( T1.CustomerName ,1, 4) = SUBSTRING ( T2.Customer ,1, 4)
```

Comment: I doubt he can make that assumption.

Comment: I too, but he says he want's first four characters, hence the query.