# Using Select left in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables : Orders from today & Records

```
Table Name : Orders from today
+-----------+-----------+
|Order ID   |   Online  |
+-----------+-----------+
|   550     |      Yes  | 
|   551     |       No  |
|   552     |      Yes  | 
|   553     |      Yes  |
+-----------+-----------+

Table Name : Records
+----------------+
|       A        |
+----------------+
|   548xxxxx     |
|   549xxxxx     |
|   550xxxxx     |
|   551xxxxx     | 
|   552xxxxx     |
|   553xxxxx     |
|   554xxxxx     |
+----------------+
XXXXX represents random number
```

I'm trying to get the full records from the Records table based on the first 3 digit of the ORDER ID from the Orders from today table.
The result that I want would be :

```
Table Name : Records
+----------------+
|       A        |
+----------------+
|   550xxxxx     |
|   551xxxxx     | 
|   552xxxxx     |
|   553xxxxx     |
+----------------+
```

I have tried using : 
`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orderid IN ( SELECT (LEFT(orderid, 3) FROM sample));`
But I only get syntax errors. I know I can use % but I don't know how to fit into the code.

Please help, thanks alot!

EDIT!
Assume the Order Id from Orders from today are not all 55%

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you can try something like [joining on LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550538/using-like-in-a-join-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE orderid IN ( SELECT (LEFT(orderid, 3) 
                   FROM sample 
                   WHERE orderid LIKE '55%'));
```

Comment: But what about `555xxxxx`? What if OP doesn't want those?

Answer (score 0):

Possible datatype conversion issues

Try:

```
select *
from orders o1
left join records r2
  on cast(o1.orderid as varchar(3)) = left(r2.orderid,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you are looking for. Let me know if you need help with it.
**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5016/1)** link.
**Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ordersFromToday (
    order_ID INT,
    online VARCHAR(4),
    PRIMARY KEY (order_ID)
);
INSERT INTO ordersFromToday (order_ID,online) VALUES(550,'yes'),(551,'no'),(552,'yes'),(553,'yes');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (
    record_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (record_ID)
);
INSERT INTO records (record_ID) VALUES (5481213),(5494833),(5505983),(5519080),(5524984),(5531315),(5549858);

     CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
       BEGIN
        # Declare needed variables
        DECLARE finished BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE orderIDHold INT;

        # cursor for each order_ID
        DECLARE orderNumber CURSOR FOR
        ( SELECT order_ID FROM ordersFromToday);

        # our continue handler for quitting the loop
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = TRUE;

        # create a table to store these values
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempReportTbl;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempReportTbl ( 
            order_ID INT,
            PRIMARY KEY (order_ID)
            ); 

         # open cursors
         OPEN orderNumber;

         # start loop
         mainFunc: loop

           FETCH orderNumber INTO orderIDHold;

           IF finished = TRUE THEN
             LEAVE MAINFUNC;
           END IF;

           SET @searchOrderID :=orderIDHold;

           INSERT INTO tempReportTbl (order_ID)
           SELECT * FROM records r1 where r1.record_ID LIKE concat(@searchOrderID,'%');

        # end loop
        END LOOP mainFunc;

        # close cursors
        CLOSE orderNumber;

       END //
```

**Output:**

order_ID

- 5505983
- 5519080
- 5524984
- 5531315